# XSD for sun-jaxws.xml

Tags: jax-ws

I'm working with some ye olde jax-ws stuff.

Pedantically, when using XML, I want the XSD/DTD schema and ideally from something that smells like a published, *eternal*, URL.

After googling, all I can find is http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/sun-jaxws.xsd which has an ephemeral whiff.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/sun-jaxws.xsd"
    version="2.0">

  <endpoint implementation="io.earcam.example.jaxws.Hello" url-pattern="/hello" name="Hello" />

</endpoints>
```

Answer (score 5):

Bah, found it.

http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/sun-jaxws.xsd

Looks safe as http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/ redirects to the dodgy looking Oracle link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/ReleaseNotes.html

Thanks to this [github commit](https://github.com/ralfebert/instant-ws-example/blob/master/shop_server/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/sun-jaxws.xml)